# How to analyze results with Teamstuido analyzer

Tags: testing, lotus-notes, analyzer

I installed teamstudio analyzer for IBMNotes when I run the tests I got a report, but how can I analyze the report(I have made the database local), as the report contain reports for the entire database.

How can I execute the report for a particular page?

Comment: This platform is for coding problems, not about software "HowTos". Read the manual or ask your vendor...

Comment: Questions about "tools commonly used by software developers" are explicitly in-scope for StackOverflow.  That said,TeamStudio Analyzer isn't exactly "commonly used", even amongst those who do Notes/Domino development...